# Safe to return const & to object passed by const &?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

When compiling the following code with clang-3.5 to the C++11 standard:

```
const String& XMLAttributes::getValueAsString(const String& attrName, const String& def) const
{
    return (exists(attrName)) ? getValue(attrName) : def;
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
warning: 
  returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return (exists(attrName)) ? getValue(attrName) : def;
                                                     ^~~
note: 
  binding reference variable 'def' here
  ...String& attrName, const String& def) const
                                 ^
1 warning generated.
```

g++-4.9 does not give a similar warning.

My belief is that clang is being overzealous and that it should work fine in this case, since I know that when this function is used the input has a long enough lifetime. (I'm pretty sure I've seen a good amount of code that seems to work this way anyways...)

I'm a little bit spooked by the fact that clang says its a "local temporary object" though. Really nothing there should be a local temporary object, and if clang thinks so and is deleting things while this function is running I would like to know why.

Does the standard guarantee that the reference returned by this function (in the case where "def" is selected) will have the same lifetime as the reference that is passed in, or does it allow that they can be thought of as two different references with different lifetimes?

Comment: It has signature `const String& XMLAttributes::getValue(const String& attrName) const` so I guess that's not an issue here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not safe.

The ternary conditional operator evaluates to a copy of its operands, in this case. Hence the warning.

You could probably work around it by injecting a nice little `std::ref`.

> `[C++11: 5.16/6]:` The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type. If the operands have class type, the result is a prvalue temporary of the result type, which is copy-initialized from either the second operand or the third operand depending on the value of the first operand.

Comment: If `getValue()` returns `const String&` then it does not evaulate to a copy: [expr.cond]/4 "If the second and third operands are glbalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category".

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Well, okay, but since the warning _does_ get generated I think it's safe to assume here that it's not the case. I could have been clearer, though.

Comment: @MattMcNabb is it possible to replace the ternary conditional operator with an if/else to resolve the issue or does this not change anything? What about assigning the ternary op result to a const String& var and returning that var?

Comment: @Ident it's not clear to me what the issue actually is, since OP hasn't posted a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As explained in my answer, we can't tell from this snippet whether it is a bogus warning, or whether it is genuinely pointing out an error because OP is calling the function incorrectly

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe you overlooked OP's clarification in comments that `getValue()` does return `const String&`?  (Of course it's still possible he's mistaken about that)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Granted I suspended disbelief there. I choose to believe the compiler over the OP. I concede that the compile is not infallible, but I don't know what else to suggest. :)

Answer (score 4):

`def` is not a temporary object here. If `getValue` actually returns `const String&` then the conditional operator does not generate a temporary object either.

However this function design is dangerous because there is no protection against bugs like this:

```
const String &bar = getValueAsString( "bla", "" );   // oops
```

The temporary string created from `""` dies when `getValueAsString` returns, so `bar` is now a dangling reference (if the default was triggered, of course).

The lifetime extension only occurs when a temporary is directly bound to a reference. Initializing other references from that reference does not re-extend the temporary's lifetime.

Possibly clang actually detected that your code does contain this bug, i.e. you bound a temporary to `def` when calling this function at some point.

Comment: The example you gave is especially relevant as the default value in the declaration is "" for this second parameter, just like in your example. Clang also seems to be the only compiler we found that detects this. Visual Studio 2008-2013 definitely also do not. As a side-note: Our library is used in production code of many applications and strangely enough, nobody seemed to have run into issues with this or gotten a warning on it - or at least no one reported issues. We fixed it for the next major versions.

Comment: @Ident cool, glad that I could help.  The effects of this bug might show up as intermittent weird behaviour (a "Heisenbug") that would be very hard to file a bug report for.